# How to fetch data from a third party using REST Api in golang

Tags: rest, go

I am trying to get data from another application using REST Api. I am able to login and get the token value but not able to get the data.

Below is my code:

```
func main() {
    url := "https://******.***.****.**:***/api/jwt/login"
    payload := strings.NewReader("username=****&password=****")
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, payload)
    req.Header.Add("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    req.Header.Add("cache-control", "no-cache")
    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    s := string(body)
    fmt.Println(res)
    fmt.Println(string(body))
    var token = "AR-JWT "+s 
    url1 := "https://***.***.**.**:**/api/arsys/v1/entry/HPD:Help Desk/?q='Last Resolved Date' >= \"01/09/2018\"&fields=values(Incident Number,Customer Login ID,Last       Resolved Date,Assigned Group)"
    req1, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url1, nil)
    req1.Header.Set("authorization", token)
    req1.Header.Set("cache-control", "no-cache")
    req1.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    res1, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req1)
    defer res1.Body.Close()
    body1, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res1.Body)
    fmt.Println(res1)
    fmt.Println(string(body1))
}
```

I can get the result "body" but not the data. Below is the error:

```
&{400 Unknown Version 400 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Length:[0]] 0xc04211c0c0 0 [] true false map[] 0xc042106100 0xc042180160}
```

Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: you are getting 400 http status code in your response try to print the errors do not skip them when you are creating the request.

Comment: The most likely reason is that your query parameters are not URL encoded.